# Import JSON with arrays of objects with apoc.load.json

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Need help importing some API json (TMDB) with array of objects.
Specifically extract a list of IDs fom the objects and set them as an array property of a node

Tried using the collect function to little result

```
WITH 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/118340?api_key=f1c5e4598bf37ad6e7e915a682ebb3b4&language=en-US&append_to_response=videos' AS uri
CALL apoc.load.json(uri)
YIELD value

MERGE (movie:Movie {original_title: value.original_title})

// We have to deal with object properties separately
// In this case a Collection
WITH value, movie, value.belongs_to_collection AS collection
SET movie.collection_id = collection.id
MERGE (c:Collection {name: collection.name})
SET c.id = collection.id,
    c.poster_path =  collection.poster_path,
    c.backdrop_path=  collection.backdrop_path

// We have to deal with the genres array
// Store them in a genre_ids array property in Movie
// while MERGEing them to :Genres
WITH *
UNWIND value.genres AS genre
MERGE (g:Genre {
    name: genre.name,
    id: genre.id
})
// Need to collect() the genres list (ids) into :Movie.genre_ids
```

Any help appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

Made it work like this:

```
// We have to deal with the genres array
// Store them in a genre_ids array property in Movie
// while MERGEing them to :Genres
WITH *
UNWIND value.genres AS genre
MERGE (g:Genre {
    name: genre.name,
    id: genre.id
})
WITH movie, collect(genre.id) AS col
// Need to collect() the genres into :Movie.genre_ids
SET movie.genre_ids = col
```

Any other suggestions welcome! ;)

Comment: not totally correct as it only import the LAST element of the list ... :(

Answer (score 0):

Several thoughts about your problem:

First, while executing the `SET movie.genre_ids = col` you get the last element of "col", the reason for this is the nature of lists, so your output is like ["something"] and not "something". But you can specify the position of the element in the list and get it, for instance:

```
SET movie.genre_ids = col[1]
```

Second, if I am getting you right, it is a bit confusing, why you do:

```
WITH movie, collect(genre.id) AS col
```

if you need to group movie with corresponding movie genre, you might find useful:

```
 WITH {movie: movie, col: collect(genre.id)} as col
```

Doing this, if a movie belongs to more than one genre, you can get all the genre specific to this particular movie, but first you need to create relations among movies and genre.

But, if you need just to store all the genre in one variable, I am not getting the purpose of this. In graph DB you have the nodes, in your case, these are the movies and genre. For instance, if you have a node "Matrix" labeled as "Movie" and "Science fiction", and "action" nodes labeled as "Genre" you can just interrelate them (it is not yet done, looking on the code you provided), so that "Matrix" has relation to "Science fiction" and "action". Then you can execute something like:

```
Match (n:Movie) 
RETURN(n:Movie{original_title: 'Matrix'})-[:hasGenre]-()
```

and you will get the movie with all associated genre.

I hope it can be useful for you!